# Auth::loginUsingId não funciona no Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Estou tentando utilizar o método `Auth::loginUsingId` no Lumen, porém obtenho o seguinte erro :

> (1/1) BadMethodCallException Method loginUsingId does not exist. in
>   Macroable.php (line 74) at RequestGuard->__call('loginUsingId',
>   array(1)) in AuthManager.php (line 294)

Testei utilizar o mesmo método em uma instalação limpa do Laravel e funciona. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No arquivo `bootstrap/app.php` deve estar comentando o uso de `Facades` no `Lumen` então descomente a linha dessa forma:

está assim:

```
// $app->withFacades();
// $app->withEloquent();
```

descomente

```
$app->withFacades(); // habilitando o Facade
$app->withEloquent(); // habilitando o uso do Eloquent
```

reinicie o servidor

Comment: muito obrigado!

Comment: Se for a resposta @Arielconti aceite como resposta da sua pergunta